# How to make an Azure Kusto sorting with grouping of results on Application Insights?

Tags: sorting, azure-data-explorer

**What I want**

Sort results by counter and group by country

**Sample input**

```
    let Source = datatable(Page:string, Region:string, Count:int)
[
    'page1', 'United States', 100,
    'page2', 'United States', 50,
    'page3', 'United States', 25,
    'page1', 'United Kingdom', 120,
    'page2', 'United Kingdom', 60,
    'page3', 'United Kingdom', 30,
    'page1', 'Russia', 60,
    'page2', 'Russia', 30,
    'page3', 'Russia', 15,
    'page1', 'Canada', 80,
    'page2', 'Canada', 40,
    'page3', 'Canada', 20
];
Source
| sort by Region, Count
```

**What I see**

```
page1 | United States  | 100
page2 | United States  | 50
page3 | United States  | 25
page1 | United Kingdom | 120
page2 | United Kingdom | 60
page3 | United Kingdom | 30
page1 | Russia         | 60
page2 | Russia         | 30
page3 | Russia         | 15
page1 | Canada         | 80
page2 | Canada         | 40
page3 | Canada         | 20
```

**What i expect to see**

```
page1 | United Kingdom | 120
page2 | United Kingdom | 60
page3 | United Kingdom | 30
page1 | United States  | 100
page2 | United States  | 50
page3 | United States  | 25
page1 | Canada         | 80
page2 | Canada         | 40
page3 | Canada         | 20
page1 | Russia         | 60
page2 | Russia         | 30
page3 | Russia         | 15
```

I get a list of pages by country, sorted by the number of visits, but the countries themselves are arranged randomly, not in descending order of visits. How to fix it?

Comment: In your example sorting by "counts" should be sufficient since it is unique. Is it possible to come up with a simple repro using "datatable" as source?

Comment: really didn't pay attention to it, bad example

Comment: Got it now. You can achieve it with leftouter join. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to calculate total sum, join by country and sort by TotalCount first:

```
let Source = datatable(Page:string, Region:string, Count:int)
[
    'page1', 'United States', 100,
    'page2', 'United States', 50,
    'page3', 'United States', 25,
    'page1', 'United Kingdom', 120,
    'page2', 'United Kingdom', 60,
    'page3', 'United Kingdom', 30,
    'page1', 'Russia', 60,
    'page2', 'Russia', 30,
    'page3', 'Russia', 15,
    'page1', 'Canada', 80,
    'page2', 'Canada', 40,
    'page3', 'Canada', 20
];
Source
| join kind=leftouter (Source | summarize TotalCount=sum(Count) by Region) on Region
| sort by TotalCount, Region, Count
| project Page, Region, Count
```

Here is the result:

[image]